# Setting a hyperlink using a relative path

Tags: hyperlink, openoffice-writer

Here are my example folders and documents

```
c:\b.odt
c:\myfolder
c:\myfolder\a.odt
```

I would like to create a hyperlink in a.odt that references `b.odt`

The direct path for the hyper link will look like this: `c:\b.odt`

However different people will have different paths. However, `b.odt` will always be in the same directory as `myfolder`.

I tried to use `./` but it wasn't working.

Is there a way I can make a hyperlink without the direct path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=54592

Make sure you select the Document option in the Hyperlink dialog (as opposed to Internet. You may also have to preface with "file://" and/or apply the relative links setting in Options -> Load/Save -> General.